# compile code with undeclared methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what is the project-setting to force code to compile undeclared methods?
This is an example of code that doesn't compile.

```
UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)self.superview;
[parentTable reloadData];
if ([parentTable.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method)]) {
    [parentTable.delegate method];
}
```

Comment: Is this code even in a method?
Why do you want to compile with undeclared methods?
I don't think you can change a setting to let code compile with undeclared methods.
But on my Xcode you can compile on undeclared methods.
If you mean with that selector try putting a SEL first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this syntax:

```
UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)self.superview;
[parentTable reloadData];
SEL selector = @selector(method);
if ([parentTable.delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    [parentTable.delegate performSelector:selector];
}
```